# Websocket client library for Python 2.4?

Tags: python, websocket

Are there any Python 2.4 compatible websocket client libraries?

[Websocket For Python](https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python) requires python 2.7

[Autobahn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/autobahn/0.4.10) requires python 2.5 (via twisted)

Comment: What solution did you settle on? Currently having the problem as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Gus: Sadly, I ended up using a long-polling GET instead of websockets -- I hope to come back to websockets again at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last version of Twisted that supported Python 2.4 was 11.1.

You might just try if that works with Autobahn .. could. I did not try.

That being said, really .. upgrade your Py.

Comment: If it does not work, it can only be for minor things .. then please file an issue on GitHub https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython .. I'll have a look if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets were not around when Python 2.4 was popular.

Your options are to backport one of the libraries You mentioned, write your own, minimal version for testing purposes (not recommended) or - the best solution - **update Your ancient version of Python! It's 8 years old!**

Comment: Python 2.4 is still widely deployed in production (mainly as part of RHEL5).  See https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata/.

As a developer, I have the luxury of running the latest versions of packages, but not all of my customers do.  That said, I'm looking at  requiring EPEL's python 2.6 as a dependency, but would rather avoid it.